# What is the meaning of "upon" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage, prepositions

In the [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/07/24/business/media/hulu-billed-as-tomorrows-tv-looks-boxed-in-today.html?pagewanted=all):

> "And it worked — boy, did it work. Visitors flooded Hulu **upon** its public opening in March 2008."

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/upon):

> *4*. immediately or very soon after
>
> *5*. on the occasion of

It seems to these two definitions are both fitting in this context.  What's the meaning of "upon" here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fifth definition was intended here:

> "And it worked — boy, did it work. Visitors flooded Hulu *on the occasion of* its public opening in March 2008."

The fourth definition was not intended, since the visitors did not come *after* the opening; they came *during* it.

Answer (score 2):

If dictionary.com is confusing you, try [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upon), which gives the meaning of "upon" as :

> 3.At a prescribed point in time

Thus, the visitors :

> flooded Hulu *at* its public opening...

"At" should make it pretty clear.